# Adding Toolbar to ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout

When I try to add `ToolBar` to `ConstraintLayout` nothing is shown in the component tree and I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/constraint/R$styleable
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:644)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:572)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:47)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:860)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$58(RenderTask.java:659)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:380)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.inflate(RenderTask.java:659)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.inflate(NlModel.java:327)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.render(NlModel.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.DesignSurface$3.modelChanged(DesignSurface.java:875)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.lambda$notifyListenersModelUpdateComplete$71(NlModel.java:460)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.notifyListenersModelUpdateComplete(NlModel.java:460)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.updateModel(NlModel.java:374)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel$1.run(NlModel.java:237)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:333)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:323)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:267)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:282)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:389)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: You probably should update to the latest Android Studio 2.2 beta and the latest ConstraintLayout release -- this should fix whatever caused this problem.